# Delete Existing Cookie Set By Iframe

Tags: javascript, cookies

If a cookie is being set by an iframe, then how I would be able to delete that cookie using javascript?

I know that putting an expired date would delete the cookie. This method might be useful only when you are setting cookies within your website, but not with iframe.

Is it so that iframe keeps on setting the cookie every second?  Such that if I am somehow able to delete that cookie at one second, the iframe would create another cookie on the next second?

Answer (score 2):

First off, if the iframe is a different domain from the domain of the page where your javascript runs, then you cannot touch the cookies from it in any way with your javascript.  This security restriction is known as the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and is a set of security policies implemented by browsers to keep one domain from messing with the content of another domain.

Second off, if the iframe insists on consistently setting its cookie over and over again, then that cookie will be there.  Other than creating a set of warring timers each trying to undo the other's work, there is no practical way to stop the iframe from settings its own cookie.

If the iframe is the same domain and the page with your javascript, then you can remove the iframe's cookie by setting the expiration date as you have indicated.  But, you cannot prevent the iframe from setting that cookie again with its own javascript or via its own server.

If there is more to your question than what I have provided here, please clarify exactly what you are asking as it isn't 100% clear what your question is.

Comment: actually i want to hide the cookie set by the iframe of another domain...i know i cannot restrict that iframe from creating cookie, i just want that, the cookie is hidden on my browser....
i know there is no way to hide cookies with javascript so i thought a way that i will first get the value of the cookie as the page load, store it in a variable, then delete the cookie in the browser adn finally when user is about the leave the website, i will create the cookie again by using the saved info so that user will never see a cookie there

Comment: You can't touch a cookie from another domain in any way. It's just none of your business. And it looks like the reason why you want to do it is exactly why it is not allowed: no messing with other sites' private data.

Comment: it means i am not able to hide the cookie by any means?
actually, by hiding cookies, i want to secure the user information.
As the cookie value will be stored in a variable and the cookie will be deleted right after window loads, no one is going to see my clients information

OR 

there would be a way to encrypt the cookie such that the plain text in the cookie is unreadable

Comment: @AwaisUmar - I would suggest that next time you post a question, you explain what problem you are really trying to solve in the question.  You cannot touch the cookie from another domain - period - end of question.  If you want to now ask a question about enhancing the security of information stored in a cookie, then I'd suggest you start a new question where you explain what problem you're really trying to solve and folks can create answers to that question.  I promise you the answer won't be deleting the cookie from another domain because you simply can't do that.